# jquery mobile alignment of split button

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a list of items http://jsfiddle.net/2Veve/5/
I wish to align the buttons to the right of the text so that it takes up less space.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is more a HTML/CSS question than jQuery

Comment: You can use float property to do this..
See my hint below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, float your links to the left, and than clear your floats

Use this for your  items

```
style="float: left;"
```

Than use this in your yes/no/may be div

```
style="position: relative; top: 20px;"
```

And lastly clear your floats after yes/no/may like this :

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Just make sure you use `left: 15px;` for item 2 - yes/no/may

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Veve/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `float:left` style to the previous `<a>` element. That will align them horizontally and make them take less space in a vertical manner.

```
  <a href="#" style="width: 10%;float:left;">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <p>Monday</p>
  </a>
 <div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
  </div>
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2Veve/10/)

Comment: I like it. Didn't know it was **that** easy to create somethin that nice.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

The output will be like below

[image]

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="my">

<style>
a.ui-link-inherit{ float:left; }
div.ui-btn-righ{ float:left; }
.ui-btn-text{ overflow:hidden; }
</style>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Kitcat</h1>
<a href="/" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" rel="external" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <h3>
                    Top Level</h3>
                <p>06 October 2012</p>
            </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Item Header</li>                    
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><h3>Item 1</h3>

                            <p>Monday</p>
                                            </a>
                            <div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">  
                            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
                            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
                            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
                            </div>

                            <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                            <h3>Item 2</h3>

                            <p>Doonday</p>
                                </a>
                            <div style="width:50%" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">  
                            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
                            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
                            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>
```